# Jupyter Notebook not opening "Error : Module note found error"

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, pip, jupyter, modulenotfounderror

So when I run this command to upgrade to notebook 7 on anaconda prompt "pip install --upgrade notebook"

This Error start to appear and my jupyter notebook is not opening.

File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Scripts\jupyter-notebook-script.py", line 6, in 
from notebook.notebookapp import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'notebook.notebookapp'

I have tried these following command but none of them worked
pip install jupyter
pip3 install jupyter
conda install jupyter

When running conda jupyter it asked me to proceed (y/n) and when I press "y":
this line comes in
Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: failed

EnvironmentNotWritableError: The current user does not have write permissions to the target environment.
environment location: C:\ProgramData\anaconda3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Issue got resolved. I have tried to solve it using

"pip install notebook" and other commands but they didn't work for me.

This is how I got my issue resolved.

- Download the Zip Folder from the provided link.
  [1]: https://github.com/Ali-Hasan-Khan28/Solved-Error-notebook.notebook.app-Module-Not-Found
- Unzip the Folder and copy it.
- Open anaconda3/Scripts folder in File Explorer.
- Paste the Folder in anaconda3/Scripts.

Now try to open Jupyter Notebook. I hope it will work for you too.

If it works, I would be grateful if you follow me on Github :).

Comment: This needs explanation. What is being accomplished via these steps? Where did the contents of the Zip folder come from? What are the contents?

Comment: When attempting to install the notebook using pip, I encountered issues, and the installation wasn't successful on my PC. Consequently, I opted for a manual approach. I transferred the notebook file from another computer where Jupyter Notebook was running smoothly to my current system using a USB drive.